# compilers for languages from 1950's and 1960's

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, super, algol

i am trying to find the best compilers (if they are actually available) for the following languages:

- ALGOL 60
- TRAC
- TELCOMP
- Superplan
- BACAIC

i don't know if any of these are still around, but it would be very helpful to get any feedback on where i could locate these.

Comment: please, give us a hint Why?  I'm curious.  Others may be.

Comment: @l--''''''---------''''''''''''  Since this is the only question where TELCOMP is mentioned on this site, I was wondering if you knew where I might find some information on TELCOMP (more than what is on Wikipedia, which is all I can find). I need to translate some TELCOMP to C, and I am having trouble with some of the syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try Eric Raymond's [retrocomputing museum](http://www.catb.org/~esr/retro/).  It at least has Algol 60 and Trac, along with other languages.

Of course, most of the original compilers ran on machines that are no longer in existence, but the museum also has a PDP-8 emulator.

Answer (score 2):

David's post went in as mine was being written ... so vote him up!

--

ALGOL 60 and Trac (among many others - but not the other 3 on your list) can be found at The Retrocomputing Museum:

http://www.catb.org/retro/

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention any specific platforms but, there is an ALGOL 60 compiler for DOS available at the link below.  A compiler, an interpreter, and the source are available.

- http://www.angelfire.com/biz/rhaminisys/algol60.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a [free Algol 60 interpreter/compiler here.](http://www.angelfire.com/biz/rhaminisys/algol60.html)

TRAC was tricky because there's a newer CMS/bug tracker known as TRAC, but I did find [one Trac compiler written in Perl](http://www.catb.org/~esr/retro/).

I was unable to come up with any links for TELCOMP, superplan or BACAIC. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

An extended version of Algol 60 is still used on the Clearpath line of computers from Unisys.
Many of the system utilities (including all the language compilers) are written in this extended version of Algol. The various variants of this language are the nearest thing these machine have to an assembler language! Here is a reference to the current manual.
[Clearpath Enterprise Server Algol Programming Reference Manual](https://public.support.unisys.com/aseries/docs/clearpath-mcp-17.0/pdf/86000098-515.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Burroughs Extended Algol for the B5500 is available as part of a complete B5500 emulator implemented in JavaScript, running in the Chrome browser. Project description and links to the code at http://www.retrocomputingtasmania.com/home/projects/burroughs-b5500